# django.db.utils.DataError: numeric field overflow - django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, decimal

I am trying migrate using django but I get this error and I have no idea what to do to fix it.

I have google the error message but all it was talking about postgres.

I have this in my model

```
budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
# I used to have this though
budget = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I was using this command
`python manage.py makemigrations` which generates the alter table fine but when I run the migrate `python manage.py migrate` this error would pop up.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message indicates that you have existing numbers longer than 8 digits (10-2) in your table. You might try modifying the offending rows if possible, or increase the `max_digits` to allow larger numbers.